# convert year and month name into datetime column for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do i convert year and month name into datetime column for this dataframe:

```
 region  year    Months
0  alabama  2018   January
1  alabama  2018  February
2  alabama  2018     March
3  alabama  2018     April
4  alabama  2018       May
```

When I do this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_sub['year'] * 10000 + df_sub['Months'] * 100, format='%Y%m')
```

I get this error:

```
*** TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can convert `year` column to string, add `Months` and use parameter `format` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) by http://strftime.org/:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df_sub['year'].astype(str)  + df_sub['Months'], format='%Y%B'))
0   2018-01-01
1   2018-02-01
2   2018-03-01
3   2018-04-01
4   2018-05-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 10):

f-string in a comprehension (Python 3.6+)

```
pd.to_datetime([f'{y}-{m}-01' for y, m in zip(df.year, df.Months)])

DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01',
               '2018-05-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

---

`str.format`

```
pd.to_datetime(['{}-{}-01'.format(y, m) for y, m in zip(df.year, df.Months)])

DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01',
               '2018-05-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple program that gets the output you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'Region': ['alabama', 'alabama', 'alabama', 'alabama', 'alabama'],
                          'Year': [2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018], 'Months': ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']})


date_1 ='{}-{}'.format(data_frame['Months'].iloc[0], data_frame['Year'].iloc[0])
date_2 = '{}-{}'.format('June', data_frame['Year'].iloc[4])

data_frame.index = pd.date_range(date_1, date_2, freq='M')
print(data_frame)
```

We can just format the date in the beginning location in the range, and the format date_2 from the final location + 1 month in order for us to avoid an index error. Formatting these values to strings will allow pandas to format them to dates with the date_range() function. We can set the index to this range since you said you wanted a column with these values, but if you don't want the dates to be your index, we could also create a column called dates, and use an insert statement to add them wherever you want. In our date_range function date_1 will be our first date, and date_2 will be our last date. We can also set the frequency to monthly so that the indexes in the date column align with the indexes from the other columns. Below is our output:

```
              Months   Region  Year
2018-01-31   January  alabama  2018
2018-02-28  February  alabama  2018
2018-03-31     March  alabama  2018
2018-04-30     April  alabama  2018
2018-05-31       May  alabama  2018
```

Comment: I'll also note that if you want a specific column instead of an index, I can edit my answer to show you how to make this a specific column INSTEAD of index column