# How to Calculate Age from Date Of Birth in pandas, Python(Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, pandas-groupby

## **Date of Birth resides in 13th column**

from 13th column how do i get the data to manipulate and produce the result only by age?

> 12-Jan-79

**Along with it, how do i sort the data accordingly the following conditions:**

```
1. Children < 18
2. Youth 18-30
3. Adult 30-60
4. Senior > 60
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post samples of Input and expected output in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: for the first question you could have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50663708/11738630

Comment: RavinderSingh13 - I have updated along with ScreenShot;

Comment: - baccandr - That doesn't help, but i need the age alone

Comment: Please avoid using screenshot and try to provide a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: [This](https://fullgrade.com/tutor-problem/what-is-the-average-amount-claimed-by-the-customers/) is link. 7th question is what am trying to attempt
[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/pavan23mishra/case-study) the dataSet which am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

# current time
now = datetime.now()

# date of birth
birth = datetime.strptime("12-Jan-79", "%d-%b-%y")

age = int((now - birth).days/365)
print("Person's age is: " + str(age))
```

You could maybe convert the birth string to datetime and get a timedelta to now.

Comment: Does not take leap years into account.

Comment: This helps, but not the second part which i covered in question

Answer (score 0):

First off my 18-30 year old friends would be surprised by being called a Youth. :)
There might be a slightly more elegant way to do this but this is the rough outline.  (I haven't tested this.  So I hope this helps)

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime
import pandas as pd

now= datetime.datetime.now()
child_split = now - relativedelta(years=18)
youth_split = now - relativedelta(years=30)
adult_split = now - relativedelta(years=60)
senior = now - relativedelta(years=200)

bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([
 (datetime.datetime.now(), child_split),
 (child_split, youth_split), 
 (youth_split, adult_split), 
 (adult_split, senior)
])
df['new_column'] = pd.cut(df['DateOfBirth'], bins,
     labels=["child", "youth", "adult", "senior"])
```

Comment: I thank you so much for response! but it has some error on it, labels(Indentation);
the unexpected ')'

Comment: take off the paren after bins (fixed in the example above.)

Comment: i still get error by the way hero! i run it on the plain as go.. i face issue with big error, which am unable to post screenshot or the error here in comments