# Plotting value versus year & month in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe `df` with variables `month`, `year`, and `value`. Each `month` and `year` combination appears only once in `df` , as I produced `df` by grouping another dataframe by `year` and `month`. Using matplotlib, I want to plot `value` versus BOTH `month` and `year` simultaneously (unsure if this is the right way to phrase this) to get a plot that looks like something akin to this

[image]

Note how the x-axis only reads `year`, but in reality each value corresponds to both a `month` and a `year`.

First, I thought to solve this by simply converting the month and year to a `datetime`, but I cannot do this since I have no 'day' field to fill in in the `datetime`. As a workaround, I thought to convert each `month` and `date` to a `datetime` just using the first day of the month as the required 'day' field, but this led to unwanted space between points that (I imagine) corresponds to the unused days between the first of each consecutive month, and the plot looked notably incorrect. So I am still looking for a solution.

Help would be appreciated as I feel this should be quite simple and I'm missing something obvious.

EDIT: Here is a more explicit example of df, the dataframe I am working with

```
df =
     year  month     val
0    2004     10       9
1    2004     12       3
2    2005      1       7
3    2005      2       2
4    2005      3      51
5    2005      4      60
6    2005      5      72
7    2005      6      73
..    ...    ...     ...
177  2019      8  115947
178  2019      9  101368
179  2019     10   96852
180  2019     11   88864
181  2019     12   38196
```

As mentioned, it should be apparent that each `year` and `month` combination will appear only once in the dataframe due to the way df was constructed, with an associated `val`. The dataframe is also sorted in ascending order by `year` and `month`.

Comment: "I cannot do this since I have no "day" field to fill in in the datetime"

Why not just set it as the first day of the month?

Comment: I addressed this, it leads to inexplicable space between points

Comment: Can you provide a MWE with associated sample data please ?

Comment: @thmslmr I have edited the question to include more explicitly the dataframe in question.

Comment: I can't replicate this: _"but this led to unwanted space between points that (I imagine) corresponds to the unused days between the first of each consecutive month, and the plot looked notably incorrect."_ Could you add a screenshot of a plot that you deem incorrect?

Comment: One of these answers to a similar question should do the trick, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663700/convert-year-and-month-name-into-datetime-column-for-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, your dataframe is already ordered and you just want to plot the values consecutively, right? In that case you could just plot the values of "val" and set the ticks of the x-axis accordingly.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

df['val'].plot(ax=ax)

tickvals = df.index.tolist()
ticktext = df.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.month.astype(str)
ticktext = ticktext.tolist()

ax.set_xticks(tickvals)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticktext, rotation= 45)
```

Is that it?